# Event Parent.function() in Iframe cross domain

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, cross-domain

I have the following pages:

www.aaa.com/a.html

```
 <input onClick=parent.miFunction() />
```

www.bbb.com/b.html

```
<script>
miFunction(){
 alert("sss")
}
</script>
<iframe src="www.aaa.com/a.html"> </iframe>
```

The problem happend when somebody presses the button in www.aaa.com/a.html. The console logs the following error:

live:1 Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "www.aaa.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (www.aaa.com/a.html:1:8)

Thank you!

Comment: See this thread for help: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098021/securityerror-blocked-a-frame-with-origin-from-accessing-a-cross-origin-frame